# Does superlevel set of a $C^2$ function have $C^2$ boundary?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N \mid u(x)>0\}$. Is it true that the boundary of $\Omega$ is of $C^2$ class?

Of course, I assume that $\Omega\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you know that $\nabla u(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$? If so, it's the implicit function theorem. If not, it's not necessarily true.

Comment: An explicit example is given by $u(x,y)= x^2-y^2$ for $N=2$ (your level set is a two sided cone with vertex at the origin).

Comment: Thank you. That completely answers my question.